# draw semi-transparent line with ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

is it possible to draw a line semi-transparent with image magick?
i want to draw a line and a semi-transparent just next to it to create a anti-alias effect (maybe that is a better description of my question :))

Michel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, looked like a wasn't reading the docs right.
The lines drawn with imagemagick are anti-alias by default, if you don't want that you have to specify it: +antialias 
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/antialiasing/